# JQUERY & PHP POST - show 00 in console.log

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I make this jquery to call a php file via post. I put a console.log to see the return of the Ajax. At moment return 00.

I'm not sure what it is the problem?

The code is:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the value of the input fields
        var inputvalue = $(this).attr("value");

        $.ajax({  
            url:"updateEstado2.php",  
            type:"POST",  
            data:{"codigo": inputvalue},  
            dataType:"text",  
            success:function(data){  
                console.log(data);
                alert(inputvalue);
            }  
        });             
   });
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php   
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['username'] != ''){

            include("db_tools.php"); 

            $conn = dbConnect("localhost", "5432", "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass");  


            $estado = $_POST["estado"];

            $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];

            $query = "UPDATE produccion.ma_producto SET estado={$estado} WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 

            $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

            if ($result == TRUE) {
                header('Location: produccio.php');
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . pg_last_error($conn);
            }   

            pg_close($conn);    

    } else{
        ?><p>La sessió no està activa, si us plau ingresa <a href="login.php">aquí</a></p>
```

The alert window show the value of the variable correctly but the console.log show 0. I do not understand well...

Please Could you help me.

Comment: console.log(data); alert(inputvalue); You are logging something different than you are alerting. That is why they are different. inputvalue appears to be what you are passing into your post. And data is the response.

Comment: run updateEstado2.php file through browser and then post output here

Comment: @user1289451 I want to execute an update query and return to the initial webpage. I have updated the code.

Comment: `echo "<br>Estado: " + $estado;` you are trying to perform addition on two string here. The result is `0`. You do that twice, hence the two zeros. You want to use the concatenation operator `.`

Comment: Ok @Patrick Q I understant the 0 result but I have updated the code with an updated query to database an it doesn't work :)

Comment: You just _completely_ changed the question. That is _not cool_! There are multiple errors with your updated code, starting with the fact that you are only sending one parameter, but expecting two, and then using completely unsanitized, unbound values directly in your query.

Comment: Ok @Patrick Q! You're right, thanks to answer my initial question (About 00 in console.log)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit statement after `if` condition.

```
            if ($result == TRUE) {
                echo 'Done';
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . pg_last_error($conn);
            }
```